# Draw path form getting location from json in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps

How to draw path from one location to other in that location is get from web services in ios?

Comment: how to want to draw path form ur current location to destination place or how u want give some clear details

Comment: post you code you have tried & explain where you have problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw lines between two locations using below code. You need to pass saddr(Source address) cordinates and daddr(destination address) coordinates

```
NSString *googleMapUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@,%@", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongtitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapUrlString]];
```

But it will redirect to Safari Browser..

Hope it helps you..